# Error trying to install qqman package from terminal R Mac

Tags: r, terminal, anaconda, install.packages, macos-big-sur

When I run: `install.packages('qqman')` it says me

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Secure CRAN mirrors

 1: 0-Cloud [https]
```

For simplicity I selected just the first one (I also tried with the one in my country). After that it returns me the following errors:

```
* installing *source* package ‘MASS’ ...

    ** package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** using staged installation
    ** libs
    Error in if (nzchar(SHLIB_LIBADD)) SHLIB_LIBADD else character() :
      l'argomento ha lunghezza zero
    * removing ‘/Users/guglielmo/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/MASS’
    ERROR: dependency ‘MASS’ is not available for package ‘calibrate’
    * removing ‘/Users/guglielmo/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/calibrate’
    ERROR: dependency ‘calibrate’ is not available for package ‘qqman’
    * removing ‘/Users/guglielmo/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/qqman’
    
    The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/private/var/folders/x1/5c_46p351wjd2h0jssbmh5_c0000gn/T/RtmpPvwdQ2/downloaded_packages’
    Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
    Making 'packages.html' ... done
    Warning messages:
    1: In install.packages("qqman") :
      installation of package ‘MASS’ had non-zero exit status
    2: In install.packages("qqman") :
      installation of package ‘calibrate’ had non-zero exit status
    3: In install.packages("qqman") :
      installation of package ‘qqman’ had non-zero exit status
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: The absence of `MASS` suggests that there is something very wrong with your current R installation, or somehow your `.libPaths()` has been altered to a state of unusable.

Comment: @r2evans how you suggest to continue? Because I can use an alias tu run the correct version of R. The problem is that I can be able to connect the correct version of R to the Jupyter notebook inside python3 with a magic line %%R

Comment: I have no experience with anaconda-based R, partially because I've seen/heard of this type of problem enough times that I have chosen to not try to fix it (I just install R natively and use it). I don't know if reinstalling would solve it, as I don't know anaconda's default behavior. If you look at the results from `.libPaths()`, you should see a list of directories, at least one of them should contain a `MASS` subdirectory. If not, then the installation of R is incomplete (`MASS` should be installed with base R by default), try reinstalling?

Comment: Do you know how to link the versione not of anaconda to the notebook ? Maybe you can read my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65458168/change-r-version-when-using-rpy2-package-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: Nope, I have no experience with anaconda-based R. (Barely any experience with anaconda in general, tbh.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved just installing not using R but using anaconda itself with `conda install -c r r-packagename`